# make an image the background and take up the entire web page

Tags: css, image

So I'm working on a website and I want to add an image as the background and have it take up the entire web page so if there's scrolling the image is still available, but I'm lost at how I would do this.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+an+image+the+background+and+take+up+the+entire+web+page).

Comment: It's not clear what C# has to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your project:

```
body {
   background-image: url("myImage.png");
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I also suggest the `background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;` so as to fix a possibly non-tiling image.

Comment: @Forty3 Updated answer to reflect your comment.